# Merging an existing github repo (with code) with an existing folder on desktop (with code)

Tags: git, github

I have content on an existing folder and also on an existing repo on my github with content.

I want merge the two together so in the end, the github repo will have both content.

I'm just wondering what the git commands are without making mistakes
(I have not git init anything yet)\

What i did: `git init` --> `git clone <url>` --> `git pull` (just in case) --> `git status` (to check) --> `git add .` --> `git commit -m "update"` --> `git push -u origin master`

Comment: Does your local folder is also a gift repo?

Comment: No it is not, I haven't `git init` it yet. I tried a few times and now I don't want to mess anything up haha

Answer (score 0):

1. Make an empty git repo on your local machine and pull the remote repo in it, or, clone the remote repo into your local machine.
2. Add your said local code to this local repo.
3. Commit the changes
4. Push the repo.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to show me the git commands? I've done what you said and it didn't work

Comment: `git init` --> `git clone <url> ` --> `git pull` (just in case) --> `git status` (to check) --> `git add . ` --> `git commit -m "update" ` --> `git push -u origin master`

Comment: I am assuming you paste the local code to the local repo before you execute the git add .

Comment: If you do so. You did everything right and it should be working now

Comment: what if I `git init` the local code (on that folder)?

Comment: It may not work. Depends on many things and cannot make comments without seeing the files and directory structures

Comment: The best way to deal with it is to put the local come on top of the remote code, not the other way around.

Comment: I see, okay I did that and now it says: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repo. Could not read from git repo

Comment: This should not be the case. Without further information, I cannot comments anything at this point. But make sure, your local code should not have any .git folder (hidden).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to merge the code changes which do not track or observed by git,

and same directory is already in the git then,

in local machine

1. git clone "your repo"
2. and add the local folder into the clone folder
3. ignore any file permission changes `git config core.fileMode false`
4. git add .
5. git commit -m "message"
6. git push -u origin master.

Now you will see the latest code changes in your repository.